# How to make users able to send and receive messages in my chat website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have finished making a chat website using html, CSS, JavaScript  and jQuery then I  published it. Here its url http://redapple-chat.com/RedAppleChat.html

But it still without function that make users able to send and receive messages through it.

How could I accomplish that?
Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just  made the front-end  part of your chat application , in order to make a real working chat you need a web server nodeJs  for example and on top of that websockets library to send and receive message in real time , or use a third party service like Firebase by google ( a real time nosql database)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a real-time database for it since you need to store the messages somewhere and access them from another place

Comment: I don't want to store messages. I just want to make user able to send and receive messages between each other

Comment: Thank you still need a place to store temporarily them so they can be received from the other place